# When do comments trigger notifications?

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications

I didn't know how to find out the answer to this question so here I am.

When I leave a comment on a answer, is there a certain amount of time before the comment triggers a notification to the author? The reason I ask is because sometimes I want to leave a short comment just to notify the author and then delete my comment immediately after.  But I'm thinking that if I delete my comment too soon, the notification won't be sent. So is there some time interval where notifications are triggered?

Comment: Worth noting that even if they did get the notification they only get an excerpt anyway

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comments *immediately* send notifications to the person who wrote the post and (if applicable) to anyone you address directly using @username.

**BUT** if you delete the comment, the notification is deleted, too. This means that they won't be able to read the comment. So, if they're not on the web, they won't get the notification unless a few very specific things happen... like the page is open already and doesn't clear the notification... but *generally* they won't get the message.

Comment: I know that if a mod leaves a comment on a deleted post - it does go into the user's inbox. Not 100% on how the rules work when a user posts a comment, that itself is not deleted, but the post related to it, is though...

Comment: The question is about deleting the comment, not the post.